# Google Analytics Not recording data

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed analytics on my [page](http://products.adnansiddiqi.me/simpleb2b/) that is it's within folder.

The code is in `simpleb2b` folder.

It's been 3 days now but no traffic was record. I also checked REAL TIME data and despite of I am on site it is not recording.

Does GA works in subfolders?

Comment: Did you set place the code in your app and is this an actual app?

Comment: Is your all webpages contain GA code?

Comment: @norcaljohnny what do you mean?

Comment: You have to add the Analytics code to your site. Is this a website or an actually iOS app of some sort?

Comment: @norcaljohnny it is a website, I just updated the question with actual URL

Comment: @Goyllo It's a landing page. Question updated with actual URL

Comment: Is it a static or dynamic website. such as bootstrap from scratch, basic html site, or more like wordpress?

Comment: @norcaljohnny it is a static page using bootstrap css framework. No Wordpress here

Comment: So I did not realize that is an actual link to your site, and you have places the code in the right place. But you only have one page. Do you not see any views at all? For example can you login to your Analytics account and see if you can see me as being on your site...

Comment: Analytics code look's good, check your analytic dashboard (make sure it is UA-50334670-3), and see the real time data, I think now you will see it.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a page about [testing your Google Analytics Setup](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083).   It suggests:

- Waiting 24 hours for data to show up in most reports
- Viewing the real time reporting to see data as it comes in
- Using the Google Tag Assistant to check for problems

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when testing google analytics on my website.
Did you have an adblock plugin ? If yes, desactivate it because that will block your JS.

Else you can do some test with their tool :
[Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk), it's a plugin for test if the google analytic code is working fine on your website :)